# spotfire increment when finding a 'true' value

Tags: transformation, spotfire

I want to create a calculated column that increments by 1 every time it meets a true in bool column. any ideas ?

in the image at left is the data table and at right the desired result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like the formula below should work

```
case  when [bool]=True then sum(If([bool]=True,1,0)) over (AllPrevious([id])) else 0 end
```